After update to Expo SDK 51 my project crashes
After I updated my Expo project to SDK 51, my project crashed when I paid for a product with a Stripe.
It's just crashing, without any errors.
I tried to update all modules.
There is no information about this on the web.
npm install expo@latest
npx expo install --fix

Were you able to find a solution ?

Updated from Expo 50->51 and immediately got a ton of errors.
Looked up the documentation for reverting Expo Go App back to v50 and I get a Babel error.
error: index.js: [BABEL] /Users/vintvgx/Desktop/bandit.studios/studio.code/RN/dpd.stats/index.js: Unknown option: .name. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.


Detected a change in babel.config.js. Restart the server to see the new results. You may need to clear the bundler cache with the --clear flag for your changes to take effect.


I had the same problem. I am using SQLite, which apparently got a new version. I had to go to legacy SQLite, so if you're using SQLite, maybe try this in your code:
//import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite/legacy';

followed up by this on the command line:
npm install expo-sqlite/legacy
(Similar thing if you're using expo-camera)
